# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/crypto/ -oencryption=aes-256

Tags: bash, shell, encryption, scripting, mount

I am trying to dabble in some bash shell scripting and have a normal function I would like to automate, if possible.  The scenario is as follows:

I have an external hard drive with aes 256 encryption, I use the following command to mount it, I only use this drive as a read only device and the process I am trying to automate is the password entry.  I have the drive password saved to a flat text file(I know, I know this defeats the purpose of the aes disk encryption, but this is my only external drive and it works well enough that I don't need to get a new one just to dump the data and decrypt the data) I am trying to find a way to use my flat text file to insert the password automatically. I am new to shell programming and thought that this would be simple, but it turns out to be quite the head knocker.

```
mount -r -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/crypto/ -oencryption=aes-256
```

I know that you can use a command to place it in fstab and have it setup like so:

```
/dev/sdc1    /mnt/crypto    ntfs-3g    ro,noauto,encryption=aes-256    0 0
```

Here is what my flat textfile looks like:

```
cat /mountpasswd.txt

12345
```

when you go to use the mount command with this encrypted drive you get the following:

```
mount -r -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/crypto/ -oencryption=aes-256
Password:
```

then you enter your password and it mount your volume. I tried a simple command line redirect of the txt file but it did not take?

```
mount -r -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/crypto/ -oencryption=aes-256 | < /mountpasswd.txt
Password:

mount -r -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/crypto/ -oencryption=aes-256 < /mountpasswd.txt
Password:
```

Either one of these commands gives the same password prompt still.  Below is my small bash script that I wrote to make a background running loop to sense when the drive was unmounted and then remounted to automatically insert the password, I also like to run this as a background program.

```
./mountencntfs.sh &

!#/bin/bash -ebx

while false
do
mount -r -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 mnt/crypto -oencryption=aes-256
0 < /mountpasswd.txt

exit 0
```

if anyone has some tips or references that would help out a lot, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to provide a better example {show us what is happening - a segment of your text file etc}. When you mount does it prompt your for a password? if so you could look at writing an expect script

Comment: Have you tried redirecting input from the text file with `< filename`?

Comment: @vahid Thanks for the quick reply and I edited my question I hope this helps out a bit more.  When you run the mount command after the carriage return you get the Password: prompt and you enter your text, as my script stands now it does not redirect my text file to the command line prompt.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reply, I have tried to redirect the text file to my command line prompt as you can see from the edited commands above, they did not seem to work or I may just be using them incorrectly.

Comment: You need to use an Expect script. The mount command is reading from the terminal, not standard input. If you need help with this, superuser.com is the appropriate site.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks I will take a look, I know of expect but have no experiance with it.  I will do some man research and check out the superuser site.